# i'm making a game for my science fair project, and i need to make a block that gives you in game currency. ROBLOX

Tags: lua

i'm trying to make a currency give block, iv'e tried almost all the tutorials on youtube and the dev forums and non of them have worked. i would love some help as it is for my science fair project and i need to get it done fast.
thank you.
Wyatt.

Answer (score 0):

sorry if this is too late but:

1. put a server script in serverscriptservice
2. enter this:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
   local folder = instance.new("Folder")
   folder.Name = "leaderstats"
   folder.Parent = plr

   local value = instance.new("intvalue")
   value.Name = "Coins"
   value.Parent = folder 
end)
-- credit to tickogrey on stack overflow
```

3. now insert a brick into the workspace
4. insert a script into that brick
5. type this into your second script:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(h)
   local amount_given = 100
   if h.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
      local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(h.Parent)
      plr:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
      plr.leaderstats:WaitForChild("Coins")
      plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value = plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value + amount_given
   end
end)
-- credit to tickogrey for this script (tickogrey on stack overflow)
```

Comment: be sure to mark it as the answer if it works and tell me if it's not working as I would be more than happy to fix it for you